# Why mysqli_real_escape_string have a connection object as a first parameter

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using MYSQLI functions in PHP for a long time.
And I always ask me the same thing:
Why the funcion `mysqli_real_escape_string` needs the connection in the first parameter? Doesn't make sense! It's just a funcion to scape quotes.

Do you know why?

Comment: [**RTM**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) You don't have to read much to get your answer, but you have to read

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php - your question is far too broad and requires more research to answer your question. That decision was made by the developers at PHP.net along with other staff involved in the development of MySQLi. So, ask them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mysqli_real_escape_string` must be aware of the character set of the connection so that it can escapes special characters properly. If you use a multi-byte set then mysqli must know. Otherwise a [sql injection is possibile](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9908/multibyte-character-exploits-php-mysql). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/711206) for more detail.

However, don't use it! Use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)!

Comment: Thank you Leggendario. I know that it's a bad practice, but, if I need to change to prepare querys, I should change a lot of lines in this website. Prepare querys are available only in POO

Comment: No, they aren't. You can use prepared statement even with mysqli

Comment: But, where isn't a way using functions to use it. A mean, you should do: `$foo->prepare()` and bla bla bla... You haven't a way to use it as: mysqli_query("SELECT x from x where x = ".mysqli_prepare($foo));

Comment: You aren't escaping data, you are bind it. This is the big change!

Comment: Exactly. I use POO MySQL in my oun projects. But in that case I couldn't. Here we can check that the we can't use Prepare in MySQLi extension using just functions. look for "API supports client-side Prepared Statements"  in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi

Comment: "client-side Prepared Statements NO" means only that the client (mysqli) can't emulate them. With mysql this is not a problem