# Why do I need to specify the connection when using mysqli_real_escape_string in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

This is PHP's procedural way of using `mysqli_real_escape_string`:

```
$city = "'s Hertogenbosch";
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);
```

As you can see, the method requires two parameters:

1. The connection / link
2. The string

Why do I need to specify the link? What If I just want to parse a regular string and then return an escaped string?

Comment: Just use prepared statements.

Comment: @pvg that's not what the OP asked, it's actually an interesting question for a change.

Comment: @Capsule It isn't, but the docs cover it well. Sanest is to just avoid `mysqli_real_escape_string` whenever possible which is very nearly always

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why mysqli_real_escape_string have a connection object as a first parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563173/why-mysqli-real-escape-string-have-a-connection-object-as-a-first-parameter?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why mysqli\_real\_escape\_string have a connection object as a first parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563173/why-mysqli-real-escape-string-have-a-connection-object-as-a-first-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how the function is described in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) (emphasis mine):

> Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement, *taking into account the current charset of the connection*

The connection is needed to determine the character set to use when escaping the string, which is important for security.